# Fetch data from Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: php, curl, google-search-console

I am writing a PHP tool which aim is to monitor certain parameters of a list of domains. I would like the script to log into Google Webmaster Tools account and check whether a domain has Manual Action applied (menu Search Traffic -> Manual Actions).

I managed to successfully log into my GWT account with cURL, then I tried to grab the source code of manual actions subpage - however all the data is loaded with javascript so cURL cannot grab anything...

I also searched in GWT API but I could not find any information on how to access Manual Actions information.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: As idea, you can do it using `WebBrowser` class, from Windows Forms

Comment: Have you tried the API? https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/ also https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/docs/2.0/developers_guide

Comment: Yep, I've tried the API, however there is not a single word about fetching manual action data...